# How to breakpoint app when it start from Action_View-intent (and not from debugging-ide)?

Tags: android-studio

I want to debug the ACTION_VIEW intent in app Z, with is started from another app, sending intent-data to app Z.
The problem is; how can I debug app Z, because it is started from another app(running), and not from the Ide's debug-command. So, without breakpoints.

Goal: I want to see the contents of an object, which is only possible from within the Ide, with active breakpoints. So Log.d, and sorts are no solution. Maybe serializing the object? Dunnow.

Comment: Why isn't logging out the contents of the intent not an option? The toString() implement on Intent is very verbose.

Comment: You can't see the contents of a whole object with toString()

Comment: I posted an answer that should allow you to debug intents in your app.

Comment: Thx. It seems that I didn't need the debug-app-startup functionality. If you just attach to the running process you can repeat the action_view intent even if it looks like the app restarted. Anyways good to know that you can halt the app on startup for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to debug your app by using the ["Wait for debugger"](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/gdb#app-startup) functionality in Developer Settings. This setting will halt your app from executing code until the debugger has been attached so that you can debug the app startup processes.

To enable this functionality, you'll need a debuggable build of your app installed to the target device. Next, navigate to  **Developer Options>Select debug app.** You should see your debuggable app here; select it. Once you've done this, the **Wait for debugger** option should become selectable. Enable it. You should be good to go. Test it out by trying to open your app from the app launcher. You should see a dialog that reads:

> title: "Waiting for Debugger" body: "Application $appName is waiting for the debugger to attach."

In app Z, trigger the ACTION_VIEW intent. When you see the waiting on debugger dialog, attach it in Android Studio and your breakpoint should be hit.

Comment: Developer Options>Select debug app <<<<on target device>>>>